# Dynamic SQL to change Database Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thanks for looking into it.

I am trying to run restore from the master database but it giving me error that I am not in the master database.

```
exec('USE MASTER; RESTORE DATABASE [' +@DatabaseName+ '] FROM  DISK = N''' + @filename + '''
WITH  FILE=1,
MOVE N'''+ @DatabaseName+''' TO N''C:\Data\'+@DatabaseName+'.mdf'',
MOVE N'''+ @DatabaseName+'_Log'' TO N''C:\Data\'+@DatabaseName+'_log.ldf'',
NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10
')
```

**Error**

```
RESTORE cannot process database 'SAMPLE' because it is in use by this session. It is recommended that the master database be used when performing this operation.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The error tells you what to do. The `exec` is still not from `master`

Comment: I am using master in exec but its not executing there, its still running the restore from sample database.